# ASP.NET MVC: Get controller's route value to build action links in model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm using Telerik Kendo UI and apparently its grid view does not allow me to build it using a foreach loop and customize my table as it provides auto-binding. In this case it would not be possible for me to add action links to the table with particular route values.

In order to solve the problem, the easiest way that came into my mind (a fully non-js approach as I really don't enjoy Java Script) was to create two `NotMapped` read only properties in my Entity Model by extending the auto generated class by Entity Framework to:

```
[MetadataType(typeod(XModel))]
public partial class EntityX {
    [NotMapped]
    public String Edit => "<a href='ControllerName/ActionName?id="+ id.To.String()+"'>Edit</a>";
...
}
```

Although this approach is working, **it has a very big problem** and that is if I change the route config, then I have to update all the links!!

My question is that, how can I generate such Urls or action links similar to the way that `@Html.ActionLink` helper does in an area outside of both View and Controller (I mean I can't reuse the LinkExtensions) in order to solve the routing problem?

Comment: Link creation shouldn't happen that low. You should separate your domain model (and/or data model if they're one of the same (code first)) from your presentation layer. Then just create the links in the controller or view, depending on your requirements(i.e. if its something like web api, there are no views).

Comment: @SteveG: Yeah that's right, but the reason why I'm doing this is because it is impossible to add links in the view in this situation. The Kendo Grid view auto-binds to all model properties and it does not allow me to do it the way I want, that's mean I can't manually create a grid using the helper in a foreach loop and then add links.

Comment: Why can't you add them in the controller.... you would typically not pass your your data model to a view, you should construct a view model, and populate it with data from your data model. This could happen at the application layer, or in the controller. This would be the perfect spot to add some links (to your view model) using MVCs routing engine to generate them.

Comment: (BTW, I have never used, or seen Kendo Grid, so if that's whats causing so much difficulty, sorry, I can't help)

Comment: @SteveG: Sadly the Kendo Gird helper is very inflexible and it does not let me define additional columns that do not exist in my model. Even if it does there is no selector to add data to those columns. Imagine you'd want to pass the `id` to the Edit button in the grid, that will not be possible. Instead it has a bunch of built-in useless Edit, Destroy button that are only compatible with Ajax.

Comment: I guess what I'm saying is, use another (view) model built specifically for that Kendo Grid. Populate it with data from the (data) model you're using now. You can make whatever properties you want on your custom view model.

Comment: @SteveG: I'm using the exact same approach, but faced the routing problem :D

Comment: @Arrrr - Like Steve G said, why can't you use a view model instead of an Entity Framework model? Seems like you could add all of the logic you want to your controller then.

Comment: @NightOwl888: In technical terms the Entity Framework's model is called ViewModel, while a non-mapped model to Db is called just a model. If I use a model instead of ViewModel, I have to implement casting to allows conversion between the model and EF model.

Comment: @Arrrr you have that backwards. Entity framework's model is either a) Mapped domain model, or b) DAO (data access object), or C) 'model' in casual speak. A view model is any custom class/dto (data transfer object), that holds ALLLL of the data that you need for your view. You can add/remove whatever properties from this, and the only thing effected should be the view.